# Dotnet Core Read Port From Appsettings.json

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

I have some Dotnet core api services. The services have to read the configuration and ports from the appsettings.json. I need to set different ports for the services and read from the common json file. How to do it and how to read the ports from the common json file.Any one try to help me.

Thank you..

Comment: U can firstly add ur app settings Json file into the IConfigurationBuilder. And use dependency injection to inject the IConfiguration and access the appsetting files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Startup.cs

```
public IConfiguration _configuration { get; }

public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
       _configuration = configuration;`
}
```

**in Configure Services**

```
services.Configure<ClassName>(Configuration.GetSection("Port"));
```

where you want to use

```
private readonly IOptions<ClassName> _options;

public ConfigService(IOptions<ClassName> options)
{
    _options = options;
}
```

> 'ClassName' should be the model to match in appsettings.json.

Comment: Thanks Ali Dogan. But i need to set the port in program.cs

Comment: @SATHEESHP If you need set the port, there's no need to read the `common.json`. Add a "`"urls":"https://0.0.0.0:8888"` in your `appsettings.json` and create a config by `var config =new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()) 
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true)             
                .Build();`  and use that config by `return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseConfiguration(config)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                ;`.

Comment: Thanks  itminus. This is ok for single service. But my need is more than one service using the same config file. Thank how can other service are read the port. because in the appsettings json has only one url

Comment: @SATHEESHP Simply read the required port in the `common.json` and invoke `UseUrls($"https://xxx.yyy.zzz.com:{port}")`. BTW, that's another question. As @[Ali Dogan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54664733/10091607) has answered your original question, I suggest you could either mark his reply as the answer or update your question to ask for a more detailed description.